# Background images dont stay on sides of page when resolution changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I'm pretty new to css animations but I've got my page looking how I want except for this one glitch.  I have a scrolling animation using scrollspy.js and when it hits a certain div images slideinleft or slideinright into the page.

[Link here](http://streamlistapp.com)

However when you hit control + mwheel down it doesn't start the anims from outside of the browser window like i would prefer it to. I'm using 1920x1080 res, for reference.

Basically, on page load it looks fine:
[image]

But again, when employing the ctrl + mwheel down it becomes this ugly looking page:
[image]

I need it to scale.
Any css gurus know what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-row panel-row-style panel-row-style-for-4-1 page left-phone has-bg feed active" style="margin-top: 100px; animation-name: slideInLeft;">
<div id="pgc-4-1-0" class="panel-grid-cell panel-grid-cell-empty"></div><div id="pgc-4-1-1" class="panel-grid-cell">
    <div id="panel-4-1-1-0" class="so-panel widget widget_sow-image panel-first-child panel-last-child" data-index="2">
        <div class="top-img panel-widget-style panel-widget-style-for-4-1-1-0">
            <div class="so-widget-sow-image so-widget-sow-image-default-eef982a7180b">

                <div class="sow-image-container phone">
                    <img src="http://streamlistapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/phone-blank2.png" width="400" height="831" srcset="http://streamlistapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/phone-blank2.png 400w, http://streamlistapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/phone-blank2-144x300.png 144w" sizes="(max-width: 400px) 100vw, 400px" class="so-widget-image">
                    <img class="screen-left layer" src="http://streamlistapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/purse-inside-screen.png">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><div id="pgc-4-1-2" class="panel-grid-cell panel-grid-cell-mobile-last animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: undefined;">
    <div id="panel-4-1-2-0" class="so-panel widget widget_siteorigin-panels-builder panel-first-child panel-last-child" data-index="3">
        <div id="pl-w5973cd6d9c123" class="panel-layout">
            <div id="pg-w5973cd6d9c123-0" class="panel-grid panel-no-style">
                <div id="pgc-w5973cd6d9c123-0-0" class="panel-grid-cell">
                    <div id="panel-w5973cd6d9c123-0-0-0" class="so-panel widget widget_sow-editor panel-first-child panel-last-child" data-index="0">
                        <div class="link-s front panel-widget-style panel-widget-style-for-w5973cd6d9c123-0-0-0">
                            <div class="so-widget-sow-editor so-widget-sow-editor-base">
                                <div class="siteorigin-widget-tinymce textwidget">
                                    <h4>
                                        STREAMING<br>
                                        MARKETPLACE
                                    </h4>
                                    <h3>Streamlist</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><div id="pgc-4-1-3" class="panel-grid-cell panel-grid-cell-empty"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    .can-transform3d .active.has-bg:before,
  .can-transform3d .active.has-bg:after,
  .can-transform3d .past-active.has-bg:before,
  .can-transform3d .past-active.has-bg:after {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    /*transform: translate3d(328px, 0, 0);*/
     transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
  }

.has-bg {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.has-bg:before,
.has-bg:after {
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 750ms cubic-bezier(0,0.5,0.25,1);
  -moz-transition: all 750ms cubic-bezier(0,0.5,0.25,1);
  -o-transition: all 750ms cubic-bezier(0,0.5,0.25,1);
  -ms-transition: all 750ms cubic-bezier(0,0.5,0.25,1);
  transition: all 750ms cubic-bezier(0,0.5,0.25,1);
  -webkit-transition-delay: .25s; /* Safari */
  transition-delay: .25s;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  clear: both;
  /*width: 100%;*/
}

.past-active:before,
.past-active:after,
.active:before,
.active:after {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.page {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    /*padding-top: 60px;*/
    z-index: 1;
}

   .can-transform3d .left-phone:before,
  .can-transform3d .left-phone:before,
  .can-transform3d .left-phone:after,
  .can-transform3d .left-phone:after {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(150px , 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(150px , 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(150px , 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(150px , 0, 0);
    /*transform: translate3d(682px , 0, 0);*/
    transform: translate3d(150px , 0, 0);
  }

 .left-phone:before,
.left-phone:after {
  margin-left: 0;
  /*right: 0;*/
}

.active .phone .screen-left, .active .phone .screen-right, 
.past-active .phone .screen-left, .past-active .phone .screen-right {
    opacity: 1;
}

.phone .screen-left, .phone .screen-right {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.phone .screen-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12.06656%;
    left: 22.37791%;
    /*width: 75.460123%;*/
}

.layer {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

  .feed:before, .discover:before {
  background-image: url(http://streamlistapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/watch3-transparent-bg-e1500713498530.png);
  /*top: -150px;*/
  height: 564px;
  width: 330px;
  /*right: -425px;*/
  right: -425px;
  /*background-position: right center;*/
}

.feed:after, .discover:after {
  background-image: url(http://streamlistapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/bracelet-e1500713698821.jpeg);
  height: 260px;
  width: 260px;
  bottom: 0;
  /*right: 15%;*/
  right: -6%;
  /*background-position: 70% center;*/
}
```

Scroll spy functions:

```
//First phone (left)
$('#pgc-4-1-2').on('scrollSpy:exit',function(){ 
   $('.panel-row-style-for-4-1').removeClass('past-active').removeClass('active');
    wow.addBox(this);
}).scrollSpy();

$('#pgc-4-1-2').on('scrollSpy:enter',function(){
    $(this).removeClass('animated');
    $('.panel-row-style-for-4-1')
    .removeClass('past-active')
    .addClass('active')
    .removeClass('animated')
    .css({
        'animation-name' : 'slideInLeft'
    })
    wow.addBox(this);
}).scrollSpy();
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @Kermit updated with code.  It's a lot unfortunately :/

Comment: This is not gonna fix everything immediately, but this `.site-inner {max-width: 1200px;}` causes your content to not fill the page's full width when you zoom out. You still have other problems, or at least one; the images for the phones don't line up with the screens when you zoom in/out. But that's a different problem.

Comment: You can go a far way by adding this `.sow-image-container {position:relative;}` and `.phone .layer {position:absolute; top:0; bottom:11px; left:0; right:0; margin:auto;}`. Now you only have to calculate the width. Which would be better to also set in CSS, but for that I think you have to set the width of `.sow-image-container`, and then set `so-widget-image {width:100%;}` and `.phone .layer {width:87%;}`. But then the phones don't resize when you zoom in/out.. oh well, gave you something to work with at least:)

Comment: @myfunkyside i appreciate the suggestions.  This is a WordPress theme so I'm thinking the theme is setting it to 1200px.  I can change this if needed since i'm modifying everything... so the long route is no problem.